# Comparing the same value from two different data sets with their respective standard deviation

Tags: statistics

The first data set has a standard deviation of 14.65028 and the other data set has a standard deviation of 18.5. If 85 is compared from these sets, which data set has the value that is more likely to be chosen?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are comparing, but even then, you might be interested in the shapes of the distributions and their means